# Convert an array-like columns to fill each row (reshape)

Tags: python, dataframe, date, reshape

This is a sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame([(date(2022,1,1), np.random.randint(10, size=30)), 
                            (date(2022,2,1),np.random.randint(10, size=30)), 
                            (date(2022,3,1),np.random.randint(10, size=30))], 
                           columns=('month_begin','daily_sales'))
```

[image]

I want to (1) create a column to be filled with each day (so the column would be `2022-01-01`, `2022-01-02`, ... `2022-03-31`); (2) break the array-like string column into each row. Something like this:

[image]

I was thinking about creating a list of days between `2022-01-01` to `2022-03-01`, but was stuck on how to fill each row with the daily data. Any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import date

data = pd.DataFrame([(date(2022,1,1), np.random.randint(10, size=30)), 
                        (date(2022,2,1),np.random.randint(10, size=30)), 
                        (date(2022,3,1),np.random.randint(10, size=30))], 
                       columns=('month_begin','daily_sales'))
result = pd.DataFrame()
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range(row['month_begin'], 
          periods=len(row['daily_sales'])),
          'daily_sales':row['daily_sales'],
         })
    result = pd.concat([result, df], ignore_index=True)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
         date  daily_sales
0  2022-01-01            9
1  2022-01-02            7
2  2022-01-03            7
3  2022-01-04            8
4  2022-01-05            4
..        ...          ...
85 2022-03-26            3
86 2022-03-27            1
87 2022-03-28            9
88 2022-03-29            7
89 2022-03-30            0

[90 rows x 2 columns]
```